# TS Error: Component refers to a value, but is being used as a type here

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to pass data down from albumList.tsx to album.tsx. Getting a TypeScript error (highlighted in the title) album.tsx.

I've used Vite to start up the React project, and I'm using .tsx extensions - not .ts.

**album.tsx:**

```
import { FC } from "react";
import AlbumData from "./albumList";

interface AlbumProps {
  data: AlbumData[];
}

const Album: FC<AlbumProps> = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(({ album_image, album_name, band_name, genre, status, year_listened }) => (
        <div key={`${album_name}-${band_name}`}>
          <img src={album_image} alt={album_name} />
          <h2>{band_name}</h2>
          <p>
            {album_name} | {genre}
          </p>
          <em>
            {status} | {year_listened}
          </em>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Album;
```

**albumList.tsx**

```
interface AlbumData {
  album_image: string;
  album_name: string;
  band_name: string;
  genre: string;
  status: string;
  year_listened: string;
}
```

```
const AlbumList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<AlbumData[]>([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/album";
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      setData(response.data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Album data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default AlbumList;
```

I tried adding 'typeof' to the album.tsx's AlbumProps interface. This caused a whole slew of separate ts errors when passing down the data props from albumList.tsx.

Comment: Can you share what `albumList` file contains? Is `AlbumData` interface exported? Is it a named export or a default export?

Comment: @AntonKastritskiy

Fixed. I made a separate 'types.ts' file, placed the types into that file, exported them and imported the types in both albumList.tsx and album.tsx. I then removed the interface types from albumList.tsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue of incorrect import/export.

This statement
`import AlbumData from "./albumList";`
means get the default export from './albumList' and let us call it AlbumData here.

The default export is the component `AlbumsList`. Instead you would want to do:

```
import AlbumList ,  { AlbumData } from "./albumList";
```

For this you would also want to export the interface `AlbumData` from `./albumList`